# Simple way to map from an ordered factor in R to the directly previous level?

Tags: r, factors, levels

I'm trying to find a simple way to find the largest factor less than X in R. As an example:

```
>f = factor(c("a", "b", "c"), ordered = T) 
>f
[1] a b c
Levels: a < b < c
```

What I want is a function "prev" which behaves like:

```
>prev(f[3])
[1] b
Levels: a < b < c
>prev(f[2])
[1] a
Levels: a < b < c
>prev(f[1])
[1] NA
```

This seems really simple but I can't find anything, any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `prev = function(f, idx) levels(f)[idx-1]`

Comment: small improvement to @user20650 function `prev = function(f, idx) ifelse(idx<=1, NA, levels(f)[idx-1])` (assuming the OP doesn't *really* need the printing of the levels order after the result....)

Comment: @agenis ; or `function(f, idx) c(NA, levels(f))[idx]`

Comment: from the examples `prev <- function(x) levels(x)[as.numeric(x) - 1]` is more what op wants

Comment: @rawr getting close! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
prev <- function(x){
  levs <- levels(x)
  index <- as.integer(x)
  ifelse(index == 1, NA, levs[index -1 ])
}
```